# substring IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string

How come executing the following

```
String p = "abcd";
System.out.print(p.substring(4));
```

Doesn't cause `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`? It just prints an empty String.

There are nothing on **p.charAt(4)** and the following

```
System.out.print(p.charAt(4));
```

indeed causes `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Please check http://www.javatpoint.com/substring For SubString StartIndex is inclusive.

Comment: indexes start with 0

Comment: as per [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) *"emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)*

Answer (score 4):

Because `charAt` expects there to be a character at index 4, and there isn't. But substring **doesn't** expect that; if there's no character at index 4, you get an empty string. If there were a character at index 4, you'd get a string with at least one character in it.

If you used `.substring(5)`, you'd get the out-of-bounds exception, because that's assuming there's at least one character at index 4; the same assumption `charAt` makes.

Comment: well elaborate sir

Comment: so you're saying, bcoz there is a letter at position 3, substring(4) is giving an empty string as OP & there is no letter at position 4, substring(5) will give exception?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look what substring(int) does:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    int subLen = value.length - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return (beginIndex == 0) ? this : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

when the index is negative you get an **StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**

in this case, the char you give is the same as the string length, so **you get a new string but empty**

```
new String(value, beginIndex, subLen)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestSubstring{
 public static void main(String args[]){
String p = "abcd";
System.out.print(p.substring(4));
 }
}
```

**o/p** : Blank_space

```
public class TestSubstring{
 public static void main(String args[]){
String p = "abcd";
System.out.print(p.substring(5));
 }
}
```

**o/p**: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
at TestSubstring.main(TestSubstring.java:4)

Answer (score 0):

Because at the end of "abcd" there is an empty string available that's why

```
"abcd".substring(4) returns ""(empty String)
```

But there is no character present at the 4th index and it is expecting a charecter here that's why below statement is gonna give you IndexOutOfBoundException

```
"abce".charAt(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from docs.oracle.com

Examples:

```
 "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
 "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
 "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)
```

If you look at the third example, it is pretty clear that it's the exact same case as yours. This particular statement, "**IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object**", the second part after "or" is pretty interesting, it clearly says that if the beginIndex value is larger than the length of the String or the negative case, the Exception gets thrown.

Hope that helps.